# Date compare Eloquent 'where' method doesn't work

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I'm desperately trying to sort an SQL request:

I want to have every row where the date attribute is less than the actual date.

Here's what I am doing:

```
$student = User::find($id)->student;
$extras = $student->extras->where('find', 1)
                          ->where('date', '<', Carbon::now()->toDateString());
```

It returns an empty Collection. That's weird because `$student->extras->where('find', 1)` returns this :

```
Collection {#229 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Extra {#236 ▼
      #fillable: array:10 [▶]
      #connection: null
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:14 [▼
        "id" => 4
        "broadcast" => 0
        "type" => "Cuisine"
        "date" => "2016-06-15"
        "date_time" => "13:00:00"
        "duration" => 2
        "salary" => 500
        "benefits" => "test2"
        "requirements" => "test2"
        "informations" => ""
        "find" => 1
        "professional_id" => 2
        "created_at" => "2016-08-19 08:18:59"
        "updated_at" => "2016-08-19 08:18:59"
      ]
```

As you can see, the date is way less than `Carbon::now()->toDateString()` that returns this value:

```
2016-08-19
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that when you access a relation using the property (e.g `$student->extras`) the results have already been pulled from the database and your using the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` class to filter the data down. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L282

If you want the database to query the results you need to use the method of your relation. `$student->extras()->where('find', 1)->where('date', '<', Carbon::now())->get();` Note also that I have not called the `->toDateString()` method on the carbon object, by doing this the query builder will convert the date to the correct format needed for your database platform.

Edit:

If you really wanted to use the collection to handle this you'd need to do something like the following

```
$extras = $student->extras->filter(function($extra)
{
    return $extra->date->lt(Carbon::now());
});
```

Comment: Thank you sir ! $student->extras()->where('find', 1)->where('date', '<', Carbon::now())->get(); totally works (with get())

Comment: Just spotted the `->get()` and added :)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to compare date with string. Try this instead:

```
->where('date', '<', Carbon::now());
```